# Where can I get the .geojson file for India and not separate files for each state/territory or any other distinction?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, qgis, topojson

Does India have a `.geoJSON` file? I want to make data visualization using `d3.js` for the states, cities and hence need the GEOJSON File representing India. Where should I start from or what should be my approach?

Also 
 [Mike's Tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) doesn't help much for a Windows guy dealing with **conversion of geographical data** for the first time.

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

here you can get all the countries geojson files..

check it out..

and there are lots of tutorials available to do the task you requested...

http://www.schneidy.com/Tutorials/MapsTutorial.html

http://techslides.com/d3-world-maps-tooltips-zooming-and-queue/

apart from these you need to search and find tutorial to learn much more concepts...

These two are the basic tutorials to start off with maps in `d3.`

Comment: Thanks @Sam. I'll go through them and advance ahead!Cheers!

Comment: URL http://www.schneidy.com/Tutorials/MapsTutorial.html does not exist any more. Please correct it

Comment: The format is not geojson but a tab-separated text file